# Please let us keep the reason for community-deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, community-user, deleted-posts

I just noticed this (on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505482/adding-jquery-to-html), but seemingly applying to all Community-deleted posts):

[image]

This is *awesome*, and I'm concerned that it's an oversight and is meant only to be enabled for developers.

If it was an oversight... can we please keep it? Humanizing the deletion reasons would be great, but even in its current form I want it to stay.

Comment: So... status-completed? :P

Comment: I stole your image. :P

Answer (score 7):

It's not an oversight - completely intentional. Enjoy the new information. :)

This is visible to all users who can view the deleted question (including the post owner).

Comment: ButTheLackOfSpacesDoesLookLikeAnOversight

Comment: @MiceElf It's not, this isn't displayed to a whole lot of users so we didn't bother with friendly titles. These are just the names of the scheduled process which deletes them. One of RemoveMigrationStubs, RemoveDeadQuestions, RemoveAbandonedQuestions, and RemoveAbandonedClosed.

Comment: I figured that would be the case.

Comment: How hard would it be to localize these strings? I foresee a lot of questions about what these things actually mean.